# A simple lib when included in a war exposes service API which return service version , artifact Id

Tags: web-services, service, maven-3, pom.xml

I want to write a simple library that can be included in any service. Library should expose one API that should return service version,artifact ID. 
One way could be to pass pom.xml path to this library then lib can parse and return the information. Is it good way to solve this problem. I also need to pass pom.xml file path which  is situated under META-INF/maven/package/.. pom.xml , relying on path is good idea ??

Suppose If I also need to return a set of file names with version info then where should I put these fileNames

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to resolve some artifacts. I suggest you to use the E[clipse aether library](http://eclipse.org/aether/). Check for the examples here : http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/